# Will Azure webjobs be down if the web application goes down?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I want to write a code to report my websites status to a status page so I was thinking of using a time triggered job that reads from application insights and reports to the status page every 5 minuts.

The only thing that worries me is that what happens if there is an exception on the website and it goes down? I should be able to report that as well.

I know that they are on the same physical space so if that is the problem both will be down, but what about the normal exeptions?

I could not found a relevant documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, although the webjobs run [in the same sandbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/background-jobs#azure-web-apps-and-webjobs) they run in a different proces on the same VM. They don't share the same lifecycle of the webapp :

> Azure WebJobs run within the sandbox of the web app. This means that they can access environment variables and share information, such as connection strings, with the web app. The job has access to the unique identifier of the machine that is running the job.

So unless the whole server goes down you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks Peter. it was very helpful